# How to get OS version of remote computer

Tags: android

My Android application knows an IP address of a remote desktop computer.
Is it possible to get any information about it's OS? (Mac or Win)

Answer (score 0):

Short of [porting nmap to Android](http://androidforums.com/i7500-all-things-root/52941-nmap-android.html), I don't think there's a good solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the remote computer is not co-operating (i.e. it's not running a daemon that you can connect to in order to ask it for its OS), you can try some fingerprinting mechanisms.

The basic idea is to interact with the system in some way and observe how it reacts. This can give hints as to which OS the host is using. As you can imagine, it's rarely perfect.

One common approach is [TCP/IP fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting): you basically interact with the TCP/IP stack of the target OS and look at some key values. These give hints as to what TCP/IP stack is used which in turn gives hints at the OS. Unfortunately I don't know if Android allows deep enough access to its own TCP/IP stack to gather all that information.